# Apply symbol from one category to other categories and retain color already set

Tags: qgis, symbology, classification, color

Is there a way to apply or change a symbol of one category to other categories without changing the already set color in the QGIS symbology window?

After setting up a symbol, I can change the color by different color-sets/ramps, but I cannot see a way after changing one symbol to copy the new symbol to other categories and keep the original colors.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the symbology?  If you hover over the color you can get the RGB values before you copy and paste.  Then you can manually change them back after.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the Layer style to a .qml file. Open it with a standard text editor like Notepad++ or VSCode. Then modify the marker for each class but keep the color. When finished save the new qml file and load it for that layer.